# additional details accordion doesnt expand for new contribution

Tags: civicontribute

wp 6.1 civicrm 5.59.3 php 8

also error message "Warning: Undefined array key "buildRecurBlock" in /home/customer/www/4nature.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%60/60A/60A6E1C6%%Payment.tpl.php on line 5"

"additional details" accordion expands for existing contributions but not for new contribution.
have cleared cache and templates_c

screen changes slightly in that line appears under "additional details" but no fields
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Switching back to PHP 7.4 fixed it.
Having said that I have another site where it is working with PHP 8

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error on civicrm 5.70 in contribution page.
Warning: Undefined array key "buildRecurBlock" in C:\xampp\htdocs\PQCRM\wp-content\uploads\civicrm\templates_c\en_US%%60\60A\60A6E1C6%%Payment.tpl.php on line 5

Warning: Undefined array key "buildRecurBlock" in C:\xampp\htdocs\PQCRM\wp-content\uploads\civicrm\templates_c\en_US%%6F\6F7\6F7BB438%%Contribution.tpl.php on line 125.

[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/14101)